# Consume RestFul PHP webservice with digest auth, jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, rest, digest-authentication

I would like to know how can I calling RestFul PHP webservice with digest authentification ?

When I create my basic request, server need auth, but I don't know how I can send it username and password. I need this for phonegap app.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://webservice",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
```

});

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data` parameter when calling `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://webservice",
    data: {username:'Your Username', password:'Your Password'},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. A prompt window opening for my identifiant.

Comment: Data just supplies parameters that are added to the URL. You could try `"http://username:password@webservice"` as the URL.

Comment: @tilix, rjmunro is correct about how to handle HTTP Auth barrier. By digest authentication I figured you meant that the digest needed to be given as a parameter. However some RESTful APIs require this to be passed as a header. There's no way of knowing this unless you provide a little more information about the API spec.